# googletest and VS2010: cannot use EXPECT_EQ

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, googletest

I've converted a project to VS2010. It includes a googletest based unit test project. When I use the macro `EXPECT_EQ`, I get the following linker error:

> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class testing::internal::String
>   __cdecl testing::internal::StrStreamToString(class std::basic_stringstream,class
>   std::allocator > *)" (?StrStreamToString@internal@testing@@YA?
>   AVString@12@PAV?$basic_stringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?
>   $allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: class
>   testing::internal::String __thiscall
>   testing::Message::GetString(void)const " (?
>   GetString@Message@testing@@QBE?AVString@internal@2@XZ)

When I use `EXPECT_TRUE`, everything works fine. Does anybody know about this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Could you give an code example for your EXPECT_EQ statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXPECT_EQ attempts to convert your data values into strings for display purposes; EXPECT_TRUE does not.

Without seeing your code, it would appear that you are testing a user type for which this functionality can be compiled but not linked ie is not implemented.

This is a common problem. If EXPECT_TRUE works, you might just want to stick to it.

Comment: This just bit me for a couple of hours. What I have is a template specialization: `template <typename T>
struct is_thing
{
  static const bool value = false;
};

template <>
struct is_thing<MyType>
{
  static const bool value = true;
};` and then I was trying to do `EXPECT_EQ(is_thing<SomeType>::value, false);` and getting a linker error. `EXPECT_FALSE(is_thing<SomeType>::value);` works fine as you suggested. Can you explain a little more what the difference is/why this is happening?

Comment: @DavidDoria: It really would be better to ask a proper question and post the relevant code. Link to it from a comment if you like.